# Backspace stops working in Flutter for desktop (Windows), if user switches input language by Win+Space

Tags: windows, flutter, keyboard, backspace

I have a strange problem:
Backspace stops working in Flutter for desktop (Windows), if user switches input language by Win+Space!

I found an issue pointing exactly same problem:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73377

But I am looking for a workaround, since they are not resolving the issue since Jan 2021.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be resolved in the Windows version with the latest Flutter but not in MacOS.

Comment: Even on Windows, it's not resolved in the master branch. Still waiting for the next major release.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still stuck on this bug. It seems there is no classic way of solving it and most workarounds are volatile and unpredictable. The best solution is to adjust how we can handle the problem at hand.

### ***problem***:

The delete, backspace, and/or Arrow keys do not work as expected on Controller-controlled TextInputs and FormInputs on Flutter;

### ***Solution***:

create two widgets, a Text widget, and the input widget then switch them as required.

### IMPORTANT

Do not use Controller on your input just use the initialValue property and `onchanged(){}` Method.

```
    menuProductProviderCart.isReceivedAmountEdit
    ?TextFormField(
    keyboardType:TextInputType.number,
    // controller: _receivedAmountController//commented My TextEditcontroller out!!!!!,
    onChanged: (amount) {
    menuProductProviderCart.setReceivedAmount(double.parse(amount));
    },
    initialValue: 0.toString(),
    enableInteractiveSelection:true,
    ...
```

When I click on bills denominations I change widget to `Text`; when I click on the received amount which is the text widget I change to `TextInputinput`:

[image: Screenshot]

This way you are in control of your code and it will never be unpredictable